# Remove white spaces from string between comma and any letter

Tags: javascript, regex, string, str-replace

I use RegExp and "string".match very rarely so I'm not so sure how to use them for some little bit complex things.Here's what I would like to do and don't know how to do it.
Here I have a  string in javascript.

```
var str= " I would like to know how to use RegExp    ,    string.match    and  string.replace"
```

I would like to delete all white spaces BETWEEN comma and any letter.So after that this string will look like this.

```
    str= " I would like to know how to use RegExp,string.match    and  string.replace"
```

I only know how to delete all white spaces from string using this-->

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, "")
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That should work:

```
str = str.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = " I would like to know how to use RegExp    ,    string.match    and  string.replace";

console.log(
  str
);
console.log(
  str
  //Replace double space with single
  .replace(/  +/ig, ' ')
);
console.log(
  str
  //Replace double space with single
  .replace(/  +/ig, ' ')
  //Replace any amount of whitespace before or after a `,` to nothing
  .replace(/\s*,\s*/ig, ',')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use RegEx:

```
\s*,\s*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dW2oT8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with regex expressions and get a decent documentation of the language features on https://regex101.com

Here is this.lau_'s solution of your problem: https://regex101.com/r/aT7pS5/1

Answer (score 0):

I would even suggest a better one that includes quotes:

```js
const text: string = 'Example "number-1" , something “ABC” , and something more.';

const regex: RegExp = /\s(?=[,"”])/g;
const resultat: string = text.replace(regex, '');
```

```
Example "number-1", something “ABC”, and something more.
```